# UV unwrapping complex strucutres

Tags: uv

What would be the best approach to UV unwrapping structures like these ? Since the structure won't be seen up-close in the final render, I tried UV unwrapping with Smart UV project but it doesn't cut it. The textures appear all over the place.

I'd really appreciate any kind of help with this. Thanks

[image]
[image: Before Baking]

[image: After Baking]

Comment: If this is a static background object you could try using projection mapping rather than UVs. Add a texture coordinate node and select Object output. You'll notice a field that allows you to select an object. Add an Empty and select this in the object field. You can then scale and move the Empty to get the positioning and proportions you're after.

Comment: Would this also work if I have to export the object as FBX ? I have to pass the 3D object with textures over to the VFX team for compositing.

Comment: If that's the case you'll need to bake the texture first. I haven't done this in Blender for a while (I tend to use substance painter) but I remember it being pretty straightforward. Either search texture baking in blender if you are only working with image textures or Baking Procedural textures in Blender if you've used any material nodes in your graph (e.g noise textures, colour ramps etc).

Comment: I unwrapped the model and tried baking the textures with SimpleBake. The process went smoothly. However, the baked textures don't hold the same sharpness that my original model has. Even the basic texture details don't transfer over ...  Any idea as to why this might be happening ? I have updated the post with new renders to illustrate my problem. Thanks.